# Detecting structural breaks in multivariate time series data

Tags: r, time-series, structural-change

I have a dataset of daily sales data (day 1 to day 365) with a number of factors influencing sales. I would like to identify structural breaks in sales data to group them in a sensible manner (day 1 to 60, day 61 to 200, etc) based on a) only univariate time series excluding features b) including features. The groupings should be meaningful, so not a black box model!

I would like to this analysis in R as I don't have SAS or STATA or Python at work place. We have a total of 3000 stores globally, so need an approach that is scalable. We only plan to do this exercise once every 6 months, so not too concerned about time it takes to run.

Comment: Relevant keywords: "impulse indicator saturation" and "step indicator saturation". These are new approaches that generally have high power, so probably better than the Chow test.

Comment: Hi Richard----why?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say that you have multivariate data when you then say you want "only univariate"? That's confusing. Please rephrase or explain more clearly.

You will need to test for changes in parameters and also variance. You will want to use the Chow test ("strucchange" package in R) to do an $F$-test to see if the model has changed. You will also want to consider the Tsay test ("tsa" package) if the variance has changed. These will flag when change is occurring.  There are also level shifts, changes in trend and seasonal pulses (i.e. Wednesday's are high and become low) that you might want to also consider.

I would point you to Autobox (but you are restricted to R -- I am affiliated with Autobox).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion, I wanted to understand how one would approach this with univariate v/s multivariate series. At present we have only univariate data but will start receiving multivariate data towards end of next year. I will look into R packages you suggest. thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like strucchange allows for multivariate....